# Are createHorizontalChain and createHorizontalChainRtl swapped?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I was trying to create a constraint chain programmatically, using the code bellow.

```
set.createHorizontalChain(
                ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START,
                ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END,
                new int[] {view1.getId(), view2.getId()},
                null,
                ConstraintSet.CHAIN_PACKED
        );
```

I have getting the following error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Left to start undefined
                                                     at android.support.constraint.ConstraintSet.connect(ConstraintSet.java:922)
                                                     at android.support.constraint.ConstraintSet.createHorizontalChain(ConstraintSet.java:883)
                                                     at android.support.constraint.ConstraintSet.createHorizontalChain(ConstraintSet.java:850)
```

Then I realized that the implementation of this method is as follow:

```
public void createHorizontalChain(int leftId, int leftSide, int rightId, int rightSide, int[] chainIds, float[] weights, int style) {
        this.createHorizontalChain(leftId, leftSide, rightId, rightSide, chainIds, weights, style, 1, 2);
    }

    public void createHorizontalChainRtl(int startId, int startSide, int endId, int endSide, int[] chainIds, float[] weights, int style) {
        this.createHorizontalChain(startId, startSide, endId, endSide, chainIds, weights, style, 6, 7);
    }
```

Should I use `createHorizontalChainRtl` which seems to work, since 6 and 7 are the values for `START` and `END` meaning this is a bug, or I am doing something wrong here?

Seriously, dealing with `ConstraintLayout` programmatically has being really challenging.

Answer (score 14):

You should use this instead

```
set.createHorizontalChain(
            ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
            ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT,
            new int[] {ITEM_ID_1, ITEM_ID_2},
            null ,
            ConstraintSet.CHAIN_SPREAD);
```

This will create a chain between all the items. If your items are created in the XML then you may need to clear the already applied ConstrainSet, by using `ConstrainSet.Clear(ITEM_ID)` to get a fresh constrainset. Then begin your new constrainset rules.

If you clear the constrainSet for an item, then don't forget to add

```
set.constrainWidth(ITEM_ID, ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT);
set.constrainHeight(ITEM_ID, ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

In last don't forget to `.applyTo`

```
set.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

Here is a fairly good example of doing this, but this person is overdoing it an connecting all the item beforehand, which isn't necessary. [HorizontalChain Example](http://www.uwanttolearn.com/android/constraint-layout-animations-dynamic-constraints-ui-java-hell/)

[image: HorizontalChain]

Here is more details about [chain styles](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html)

[image: Chain Styles]

[Here is also a Wiki](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Managing_Constraints_using_ConstraintSet) on how to work with constrainlayout in code.

Comment: I think maybe the LEFT and RIGHT are flipped in the createHorizontalChain call example? but thanks for the example, got me close enough to realise that :)

Comment: why can't we use START and END and we need to use LEFT and RIGHT?

Comment: This answer is suggesting to use anti-patterns (LEFT RIGHT), and I'm not sure how chain options are related to anything in this question.

Comment: this code has ah error, must be:  
ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT,
ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT
in that order.